# Publish npm package to gitlab registry

Tags: npm, gitlab, registry, package-managers

I am trying to publish a package to a private Gitlab npm registry.  I am following [gitlab's docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/index.html) on how to do this, but something isn't working right.

First, I created a personal access token with all access.  Then, in my terminal, as per [their docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/index.html#authenticate-with-a-personal-access-token-or-deploy-token), I set

```
npm config set @myproject/my_package http://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/myproject/my_package/packages/npm/

npm config set -- http://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/myproject/my_package/packages/npm/:_authToken "<my_token>"
```

Though there is no output from these commands, so I'm not really sure what its doing or if its working as intended.

Next, in my package.json, I set the name and publishConfig to what you would expect for a scoped package:

```json
{
  "name": "@myproject/my_package",
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "restricted",
    "@myproject/my_package": "https://gitlab.com/af56/myproject/my_package/packages/npm/"
  }
}
```

I then run `npm publish`.  I see that the package is being built, but then I get an error

```
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in to https://registry.npmjs.org/npm ERR! 
need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-09T00_00_38_418Z-debug-0.log
```

I don't understand why npm is trying to reach npmjs when I configured it to use gitlab as  the registery, both through the command line, and in the package.json.  I've published packages to npmjs before, but never to gitlab registry, so I'm not sure what steps I'm missing / doing wrong.